# Is the Schwartz Function space separable?

Tags: functional-analysis, fourier-analysis, distribution-theory, schwartz-space

Let the Schwartz function space on $\mathbb R^n$ be endowed with its usual metric structure. Is this space separable? Can anyone give a reference?

Comment: I'd say the analytic Schwartz functions are dense.

Comment: Thanks! But what do you mean by analytic Schwartz functions? Do you mean real analytic ones or complex analytic ones? Could you give a link to the references?

Comment: $f \ast m^n e^{-\pi |m x|^2} \to f$ and it is (real) analytic

Comment: Thank you for your comment! So how is the set of analytic Schwartz functions related to the countability?

Comment: An analytic function is fully determined by the sequence of its derivatives at $0$.

Comment: Aha! Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 5):

Schwartz space is separable as a metric space.

Indeed it is isomorphic to $\mathfrak{s}$, the space of sequences $(x_n)_{n\ge 0}$
of fast decay with topology defined by the seminorms
$$
||x||_k=\sup_n\  (1+n)^k |x_n|
$$
In $\mathfrak{s}$ take almost finite sequences of rationals and that gives a countable dense subset.

Comment: May I have a reference to your answer?

Comment: You mean, more precisely, a reference for the isomorphism of $S$ with $\mathfrak{s}$? In that case you can see https://aip.scitation.org/doi/abs/10.1063/1.1665472 but the proof is not very well written. Simon gave a much better presentation in section 6.4 on Hermite expansions of his book "Real Analysis : A Comprehensive Course in Analysis, Part 1" https://bookstore.ams.org/simon-1/